# Gnome Terminal Colors not displaying correctly, Vim too

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

### Gnome Terminal Monokai Theme (Colors are wrong)

I downloaded the Monokai theme and my blues and greens are clearly off.

[Gnome Terminal Monokai Theme](https://github.com/pricco/gnome-terminal-colors-monokai)

### Vim Issues

Also I am using [256-grayvim theme](http://wstaw.org/m/2010/04/16/2010-04-16-230848_640x772_scrot.png) and mine clearly does not look like that.

**I tried the following already with no avail:**

- `set t_Co=256`
- `.profile export $TERM to 256`

Weird thing is my terminal is displaying 256 colors (tested with perl script below).

### My Screenshots

[image: pearl256colors]

[image: 256grayvim]

---

#### Followed these directions with no avail.

[256 colors in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim)

[256 colors setup for console Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_setup_for_console_Vim)

#### System Settings

- `tput color` returns xterm 256
- ubuntu 15.04
- kernel 4.1
- Vim 7.4.488